# Sorting Array [0]

Tags: php, sorting

```
Array ( [0] => wilson ) 
Array ( [0] => umkk )
Array ( [0] => audiok ) 
Array ( [0] => Futurama )
```

I have the above users array, i'm trying to sort it alphabetically so the result looks like this

```
audiok
futurama
umkk
wilson
```

This is my php code from those lines:

```
$arr1 = explode("\n", $users);

            sort ($arr1);
            print_r($arr1);
```

Why isn't sort () working? It doesnt sort it at all.. what am i doing wrong? I'm new to php programming, i have looked on the php manual and have not been able to sort it after trying all these different examples posted there.

Thanks in advanced.

Edit:

```
preg_match_all('/control\?user=(.+?)&data/', $linklong, $users) 
$users = $users[1][0];}
```

if i print $users all the users are displayed nicely, but when i tried to sort them it tells me is not array, so i took $users, and did explode to create the array... i'm sorry im not very programming savy –

Comment: why are you trying to explode again ?

Comment: Because your'e sorting a __nested__ array.... use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: Your top snippet cannot be the contents of `$arr1` because `explode` would not produce something like that. It likely cannot be the contents of `$users` because `explode` does not work on arrays. So what exactly is the deal with the question?

Comment: what is the output before and after the sort?  Also, what is your input, perhaps you dont have a new line character in the input.

Comment: please show us what print_r($arr1) shows?

Comment: Actually, show us a var_dump() of $users

Comment: var_dump($users); put this line in your code and you'll get an output. Post that output here please so that we could understand it types and structure etc

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0=>'wilson');
$array2 = array(0=>'umkk');
$array3 = array(0=>'audiok');
$array4 = array(0=>'Futurama');

$array = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3,$array4);
natcasesort($array);
echo '<pre>',print_r($array),'</pre>';
```

Or if you have text that is 4 names on 4 different lines that you want to explode and sort:

```
<?php
$text = <<<EOD
wilson
umkk
audiok
Futurama
EOD;

$arr = explode("\n",$text);
natcasesort($arr);

echo '<pre>',print_r($arr),'</pre>';
```

[natcasesort() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php)

Answer (score 0):

asort() is the function that u need. Following URL contains the example and the output.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: `asort()` would put `Futurama` first

Comment: as shown in the given url for reference, the asort() function sorts the array based on the value. Thus it sorts it alphabetically as needed.